# How to add multiple elastic search connections to a Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have 2 elastic search servers that I need to add the connection to the spring boot project. For one connection following is the code I have,

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = {"packageName"})
public class ES {

    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient client() {
        CredentialsProvider cp = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        cp.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

        return new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("host", "port", "https"))
                        .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpAsyncClientBuilder -> httpAsyncClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(cp)
                                        .setKeepAliveStrategy(new DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy())));
    }
}
```

So how can I add the other server connection? If I duplicate this class and add other server connection details will it work? And also I need to separate the indexes. I mean for example I need the index `entity1` must be only in `server 1` and the index `entity2` must be only in `server 2`. Is that possible? Really appreciate if anyone can assist me.

Comment: Did you tried to depluciate the client with a diferent method name ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not possible with Spring Data Elasticsearch. A repository uses the `ElasticsearchOperations` bean provided by the Spring context, and this bean uses the configured `RestHighLevelClient`. There is no way to configure multiple connections to different clusters.

**Edit:**

You could have one connection configured as the default using the beans and then you can use this injected as `ElasticsearchOperations` and used by the repository method.

For the second connection you'd need to create a new `RestHighLevelClient` like you already do and then create an additional `ElasticsearchRestTemplate` passing in this second client; use an injected `ElasticsearchConverter` as the second constructor parameter. You can check the code in `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.config.AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration` how it's done there.

With this second `ElasticsearchOperations` instance you can work against the second cluster, but you will have to use the methods of this interface and cannot use repository methods for that.

**Edit 29.01.2024:**

I recently wrote a short article about doing this: https://www.sothawo.com/post/2023/10/18/use-two-different-elasticsearch-clusters-with-spring-data-elasticsearch/

Comment: Ok I got it. Are there any way that we can do it with manual way? I mean without spring bean etc but only plain java?

Comment: Instead of using `ElasticsearchOperations` what if I use [this way](https://spinscale.de/posts/2020-04-15-introduction-into-the-elasticsearch-java-rest-client.html) to create index and save?

Comment: The issue is I am already using `{"elasticsearchOperations", "elasticsearchTemplate"}` for server . So I think I will get bean issues if I create right?

Comment: You could give the second instance a different bean name or a qualifier or mark the first one as primary. I did not try it out and alas don't have the time to do currently.

Comment: Of yourse you can work directly with a `RestHighLevelClient`. That's not Spring Data Elasticsearch anymore then, but plain Elasticsearch client use.

Comment: Yes I have used plain Elasticsearch client and it is working, now. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case both servers belong to the same ES cluster, `RestClient.builder` accepts an array of HttpHosts to connect to. The client (which under the hood is the ES low-level REST client) will round-robin requests to these hosts.

[More info](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-low-usage-initialization.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But how the `repository` will identify it's own es server?

Comment: Repositories do not belong to a specific server. Repository uses the RestClient under the hood which will round-robin your requests to these hosts.

Comment: If I add both of with `RestClient.builder` how to separate the indexes? I mean for example I need the index `entity1` must be only in server 1 and the index `entity2` must be only in server 2. Is that possible?

Comment: Do server 1 and server 2 belong to the same ES cluster?

Comment: No those are two different server instances

Comment: So, as Meisch mentioned, currently there is no way to configure multiple connections to different clusters.